# Rules around Instant Level 90

Tags: world-of-warcraft

You get an Instant Level 90 boost with your Warlords of Draenor purchase, and can also buy these seperately.

A few questions:

1. When you boost a 60+ character, it receives a boost to professions. If you do not have any, do you get to choose them or are there defaults that you will get assigned?
2. How long can you save the Instant Level Boost, or do you have to use it immediately?
3. After buying either the expansion or the boost itself, how do I apply it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To answer All your Questions:

**What happens if you don't have any professions?**
You will receive Professions that are useful to your character class. The following Professions are automatically Learned depending on your Armor Type:

- Cloth Armor: Tailoring and Enchanting
- Leather/Mail Armor: Skinning and Leatherworking
- Plate armor: Mining and Blacksmithing

As you can see, those Professions are decent, however most of the time it's better to log in and learn 2 new Professions of your choice.

**How lang can you save the Level Boost**
Once you've paid for it you can basically wait forever to use it. Currently there is no time limit however this might change in the future (although it's rather unlikely to happen).

**How do I apply the Level Boost?**
You will see an Icon in the Top right corner of your Character Select screen. If you click it you are prompted to choose the character. After that you have to select the Talent specialization of your char (or fraction if you are a Pandaren). If you've done all this you are asked one more time to confirm your choice and if you click yes your level 90 Character is ready.

Sources: [Character Boost FAQ](https://us.battle.net/support/en/article/level-90-character-boost) and personal experience

Comment: Good answer! By any chance can you include a source?

Comment: Do the professions skill up include the standard recipes (that you could learn from trainers) for the items you can craft?

Comment: @HowlinWulf It includes all the mists of pandaria recipes that you learn from the trainer. However, you have to learn all the older recipes separately. My BS/Engineer paladin had another 2-300 recipes to learn in total. This is not exactly the same as is mentioned on the FAQ, because that says that you need to learn the recipes yourself. So expect another 1K gold to go towards those.